# I'm getting an error ' LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}' repeatedly every time I use Quick Build

Tags: compiling

I've updated all MikTeX packages, but still it is not working. It started suddenly, before that it was working fine! Please help.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention **which LaTeX editor** you are using.

Comment: you should show a small but complete example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved by OP: "Thank you very much for your reply @Dr. Manuel Kuehner. I proceeded to follow your solution, but then I noticed that before '\documentclass{}' there was an extra 7! This was the reason for the problem. Anyway, thanks for your time. I appreciate it."

Comment: **Hint:** Next time help yourself and others by providing a so-called MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: This was not that kind of question where showing a MWE was possible! I'm using Latex (Texmaker) for more than 8 years for my research works and this particular document was already 15 pages long. As I said, the problem was an unusual case and started suddenly, out of the blue! Somehow that 7 got typed at the very beginning without my knowledge and therefore I didn't know where to look for the error. But thanks to the suggestion, I looked at the beginning of the document to find that typo.

Comment: I get your point. It was meant as a helpful hint. My thinking was that if you would have provided an MWE and tested the MWE on your system then you maybe would have discovered that the MWE can be compiled. This may have helped you to figure out the real problem quicker. See also Ulrike's comment (it is ok to not listen to me but ALWAYS listen to Ulrike :)).

Comment: Hint: If the error is `Missing \begin{document}` the problem is almost invariably in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are in your main document (that contains `\documentclass{}`) and tell Texmaker that this is the "Master Document" (assuming you are using Texmaker).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @Dr. Manuel Kuehner. I proceeded to follow your solution, but then I noticed that before '\documentclass{}' there was an extra 7! This was the reason for the problem. Anyway, thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: This is why it's important to provide actual code that recreates the problem :)